# is there any zero knowledge proof could prove ciphertext?

Tags: encryption

There are two ciphertexts which encrypted by latticed-based homomorphic ecryption and comparable encryption respectively. I want to verify their plaintexts are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Lattice based cryptography produces noisy ciphertexts, and the amount of noise grows as homomorphic operations are performed on them. So, in order to perform arbitrary computations, ciphertexts need to be periodically refreshed. This refreshing procedure, called bootstrapping, turns an encryption scheme with bounded homomorphic properties into a fully homomorphic one. Bootstrapping is by far the main efficiency bottleneck of current FHE schemes.

Following are two important implementations of Lattice based FHE schemes.

- [HELib](https://github.com/homenc/HElib)
- [PALISADE](https://gitlab.com/palisade/)